# Proving correctness of algorithms.

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was looking at posts on stackoverflow about proving correctness of different algorithms, and they all seem to be about proving algorithm X or Y. I'm computer science student and I realized that a lot of CS students (including me) are struggling with this concept, and I haven't found any post that explains general approach of proving correctness of programs/algorithms. Wiki and Youtube both aren't really helpful, since both have very limited amount of information on current subject.

Could you explain step by step the "general" approach (if there is any) to proving correctness of algorithms, explaining on the way what loop invariants are for, why is it sometimes enough to prove that algorithm is *partially* correct, instead of *totally*, with all the little details and nuances, without leaving out anything relevant. And just to make sure that anyone could understand this concept, let's prove correctness of binary search algorithm (In a most general way possible).

```
int binSearch(int[] a, int x) {
    int l = 0;
    int r = a.length - 1;
    int m = 0;
    while (l <= r && a[m] != x) {
        m = (l + r) / 2;
        if (a[m] > x)
            r = m - 1;
        else if (a[m] < x)
            l = m + 1;
    }
    if (a[m] == x)
        return m
    else
        return -1;
```

Comment: Informal proofs are by humans and for humans, and there is a culture there that is difficult to convey concisely. I would advise another branch of mathematics for learning the culture (discrete math is the usual choice for CS curricula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between an algorithm and its implementation in a particular programming language. It's also entirely possible to correctly implement an algorithm while you cannot "prove" it is correct! (You can write a correct binary search without knowing 'why' it will always work for a sorted list.)

Let's write out the algorithm for your example: binary search.

In a sorted list of *n* elements long, the searched value *x* may occur in that list or it may not.

The 'length' of the list, that is, the bounds in between where *x* may be present, can be represented by indexes *l* and *r* such that it is guaranteed that if *x* is in the list, it will be in a position between *l* and *r* (inclusive) and if it's not between these values (again, inclusive), it will not be in the entire list. This is always true for a *sorted* list. An early check may be to test if *x* is lower than the first element value or higher than the last; if so, it is 'outside the bounds' and you are done.

1. If the length of the list fragment bound by *l* and *r* is 1 element only, then if `element[l] = x` the search value is found, else it is not in the list.
2. If the length of the list fragment is greater than 1, pick a random element between *l* and *r* (usually, the midpoint is chosen). Its value can be less than, equal to, or greater than *x*.
3. Since we *know* that in a sorted list *x* may be anywhere between *l* and *r* (if it is in the list), you can update either *l* **or** *r* (depending on the result of step #2) and the overall statement *elem[l] <= x <= elem[r]* will **still be true**. One of *elem[l] <= x <= elem[m]* and *elem[m] <= x <= elem[r]* must be true, which determines which end point you can move.
4. Every change of *l* will move it towards *r*; every change of *r* moves it towards *l*. Repeat from step #1 until the interval *l..r* is only 1 element long and thus step #1 is `true`.

Since every comparison *must* update either *l* or *r* towards the other, the list fragment will get shorter on every iteration. Therefore, logically, it will end up with a length of 1 and step #1 will halt the algorithm, and the selected value will be as close as possible to the value of *x* (in the sense that the lower element has a value less than *x* and the higher element has a value greater than *x*).

This describes step by step what happens, and has a clear Halting state, which will always return the correct result. There is no ambiguity in any step -- the wanted element *will* always be between *l* and *r*.

This is a logical proof of Binary Searching working the way it does (that is, it will always return the desired result), but of binary searching *only*. Other algorithms need different proofs.

Somehow I get the idea you are looking for a Proof of Proofs: "proving correctness of different algorithms". That is just about the Holy Grail of Computation. You should read up on Turing's Halting Theorem (which, if I remember correctly, states that there is no such thing).